# Installing ns-allinone-2.29.3 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, ns2, otcl

I am trying to install Network Simulator allinone package (ns-allinone-2.29) on Ubuntu 11.10. I am actually interested in simulating bluetooth using the UCBT extension meant for ns. http://www.cs.uc.edu/~cdmc/ucbt/ states

`Plese install ucbt-0.9.9.2.tgz on the top of ns-allinone-2.29.3`

I get the following error -

```
configure: error: otcl is required but could not be completely found.
Please correct the problem by telling configure where otcl is
using the argument --with-otcl=/path/to/package,
or the package is not required, disable it with --with-otcl=no.
tclcl-1.17 configuration failed! Exiting ...
Please check http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/ns-problems.html
for common problems and bug fixes.
```

What could be the reason for this error?
Also, I would like to know which is the preferred OS for working on Network Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to use an older version of Ubuntu such as 11.04 or older because with this version you will not get all the features of the ns2 that if you could install it.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you, but Fedora 12 Constantine was a much better choice than Ubuntu when it came to installation of NS2 with UCBT extension.